# system wide proxy in arch linux

Tags: vpn, archlinux

I'm using Arch Linux with KDE Plasma.
I want to set a http proxy to use as system wide but when I set it in KDE settings, Nothing happens!
how can I use my proxy as a system wide proxy?!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I've solved my problem.

I'm writing this here if someone have this problem in the future, can solve it.
first you have to install proxydriver:

```
$ yaourt -S proxydriver
```

then you can change your system proxy with gnome control center or kde settings. just for first time you have to edit this file:

```
# vi /etc/proxydriver.d/default.conf
```

just open it and you'll know where you have to edit!

and thanks from that users who give negetive on my question but they can't answer this!